# RxJava: two calls during timeout

Tags: java, timeout, rx-java

My task is to call subscriber if two or more events happens durng timeout. First event triggering timeout, if nothing happens during timeout - it will be started again with the next one and so on.
I'm using following construction:

```
    boolean trigger = false;
    Observable.interval(...)
    .filter(...)
    .timeout(10, TU.SECONDS, Observable.just(false))
    .subscribe(par ->
      if (par){
        if (trigger){
          twoTimesInTimeout();
        } else {
          trigger = true;
        }
      } else {
        trigger = false;
      }
    )
```

Maybe there is a way to go without trigger?

Comment: Please clarify. What do you want to happen?
The "trigger" variable is very non-functional, i.e. against the aims of RxJava. There is definitely a way to do this without that variable. But I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Perhaps add an example.

Comment: I have a timeout, say 10 seconds. Then I have an Observable that produces A | B | C. I filter Observable for A. If I got two or more A in 10 seconds, I need to call Subscriber.

Comment: But it's not like a `buffer()` because I need timer be `A` - dependent. It starts only when first `A` produced. Like a security system: if it see something suspicious, it goes into warn mode for 10 seconds. If nothing happens in 10 seconds - it calms down. If something happens - alarm turns on.

Answer (score 0):

This method will re-emit each emission if there is another emission within a given number of milliseconds. I compare the time each successive emission is emitted and re-emit if the time-limit is satisfied.

```
<T> Observable<T> emitIfWithin(Observable<T> obs, long millis){
    zip(obs.timestamp(), obs.skip(1).timestamp(), Pair::new)
        .filter(pair -> pair.first.getTimestampMillis() - pair.first.getTimestampMillis() < millis)
        .map(pair -> pair.first);
}
```

And then call it with your desired filters to maximise re-use:

```
emitIfWithin(observable.ofType(A.class), 10000)
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks nice. But now I realize I've been not completely honest:(  I need both of events for my algorithm: it works like a security system I have described. `trigger = true;` is not only about the trigger, but setting system in warning mode, its more like `trigger = true; warnTheSystem();`  Shame on me:(

Comment: then just replace `map(...)` with `map(pair -> new Pair(pair.first.getValue(),pair.second.getValue()))` and change the return type to `Observable<Pair<T, T>>`

Comment: But wouldn't it wait for the second emit to make mapped `Pair` emission? For example first one is at 00:10 sec and second at 00:15, my subscriber will react on 00:15?

Comment: I think I can use `each` to enable `warnMode`

Comment: Of course it would wait until the second emission before emitting the pair, That is the first moment that we know we should emit.
I don't know what you mean be `each` or `warnMode`.